# I need a regex for alphanumeric string of starting with numeric. The length of the expression should be limited to 6

Tags: regex

I need a regex for alphanumeric string starting with numeric. The length of the expression should be limited to 6.

This regex is for data entry restriction. If i am not entering a number first it should not allow me to enter alphabets.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question- if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to David B's recommendations, it also helps us to help you if you mention what implementation of regex you're using (PHP, JS, etc.)

But in general, here's the regex you're looking for.

```
\d[a-zA-Z]{5}
```